# I need to rotate a 64 bits key

Tags: c

I have to do for a school projet a Feistel cipher. 
For this , I have determine a secondary key from the main key.
First I have to rotate the primary key to the left of 4 bits and repeat this step N times in function of the current lap.
And then I have to take the last 32 bits of this new key.

My code is :

```
int *encrypt(int *left, int *right, long long p_key)
{
  int   i;
  int   temp;

  i = -1;
  while (++i < 8)
    {
      temp = *right ^ f(p_key, i);
      if (i != 7)
        {
          *right = *left;
          *left = temp;
        }
      else
        *right = temp;
    }
  return (left);
}
```

and

```
long long f(long long key, char tour)
{
  int   i;
  long long mask;
  long long last32bitsvalue;
  i = -1;
  while (++i != tour)
    {
      key = key << 4;
    }
  mask = (1 << 32) - 1;
  last32bitsvalue = key & mask;
  return (last32bitsvalue);
}
```

Also i have to take take out a bit of each byte for bit parity but I have no idea how I could do that, someone can explain ?

Else do you see any mistakes I could make?

Thanks !

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: Problem is that when I encrypt the subject of the project, it dont gives me the same encrypt that they gave to us and I am using the same key. Even the first bytes are wrong.

Comment: Shifting into the sign bit and shifting by more than the width is UB. The former often works nonetheless (though still should be fixed, probably by declaring the variables unsigned), the latter is likely an issue: `(1 << 32)` should be `(1ull << 32)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not rotating, you just shifts key to the left. It means first 4 most significant bits are gone.

You are supposed to store them and move to the right.

```
int8_t offset = 8 * sizeof(key) - 4;
int64_t overflow = (key >> offset) & 0xf;
int64_t key = (key << 4) | overflow;

//if you use unsigned, you can shift directly
uint64_t key = (key << 4) | (key >> (8 * sizeof(key) - 4));
```

> overflow => 0101 0001 >> 4 => 0000 0101
>
> key => 0001 0000 | 000 0101 => 0001 0101